# Time to switch instructors? or not?

Tags: flight-training

To give a bit of background before I get into my scenario, I recieved my PPL in Canada two years ago, and then my night rating about 10 months after that. I was able to remain current but due to financial reasons I only just recently was able to go for my CPL.

The instructor I have now was just randomly assigned to me, and took me up to show that I was able to do upper airwork. Needless to say my skills had eroded, which wasn't all that surprising - so it took a few lessons to get all that rust off. Then we decided to practice diversions, which again my skills were eroded.

Now I have been studying all these maneuvers at home and playing them over in my head to get all the steps down pat, which I know isn't the same as flying. Having said that, I am not flying that regularly either which is down to my schedule and things pop up sometimes on my 4 days off so I do take full responsibility for that no doubt.

My instructor isn't all that encouraging though, he basically is trying to tell me without saying it, "stop wasting your money and stop flying". He doesn't try to really help, he basically criticizes me, which I am able to take, and he's not wrong on what he is saying -  but that's it, he doesn't really go much further than that.

He also has mentioned that my walkarounds are taking too long and that I am not fast enough at it, and I should be quicker with checklists, when all I am doing is being methodical and sure that I am not leaving anything out. Another thing is, half the time we don't do a briefing/debrief so the first time we practiced diversions again, we went up without a CPL diversion briefing and then we came back and he basically told me that wasn't up to CPL standard and this is how we do it.

So shouldn't he have done a debrief so I could know that? Another thing is he was late for a lesson by a half hour, but gave me flack for being 5 min late... I do feel frustration with him but I am not one to talk openly about that frustration so maybe I should grow a pair and talk to him about it? Before switching instructors?

Sorry for this being long but thanks to anyone who has tips or criticism.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Because this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, we generally don't answer questions that ask for opinions, discussion, suggestions etc. The [tour] may be helpful if you're not familiar with how the site works. You'll probably get a much better response on an actual discussion forum, where you can ask follow-up questions and get multiple points of view.

Comment: I'd recommend getting a flight simulator setup at home, so that you can practice a bit before getting back into the plane, and again after each session. It's not 100% the same, but it can help with maneuvers, timing, and familiarity.

Comment: How old are you? If you're over, say, fifty, it is to be expected that you may take a longer than otherwise expected. Also, how old is the instructor? That can enter into it as well. And, though it may be impossible to find out, how many hours of instruction has he given. My experience as a former chief flight instructor at a U.S. FBO that did a lot of training, is that it takes a few hundred hours of instructing to really figure out how to tailor your instructing to individual students. In the end remember that, for all practical purposes, he is your employee.

Comment: The question is off-topic (opinion based), but the answer seems to be a clear "yes" - switch!

Comment: Regarding preflights, I have the same issue as you; I like being thorough. (If I'm a few thousand feet into the air with nothing between me and certain death except for that machine, even though I mostly trust it will get me both up and back down safely, if there's a problem then I sure as \* want to catch it on the ground if I can!) What I ended up doing is to book the aircraft for a brief period before the beginning of the booking with the instructor. As long as one is paying only for flight & instructor time, that gives time to give the aircraft a good preflight w/o stressing out over time.

Comment: I did not realize this was an non opinion based forum my bad. I am just 26 and he is not much older I dont think, he is a relatively new instructor and this flying school is relatively busy during the summer so he is as fresh as they come

Answer (score 4):

It's your money. Spend it on someone you are comfortable with can have a good rapport with.

Answer (score 2):

It's just you and the instructor up there.

No way would I stay if you are not feeling good about
it.  Would not want to think about how both of you would react in a real emergency.

Nothing wrong with changing the instructor, or even flying schools.  Fresh start somewhere else might be good.

First, I would speak to the boss there.  But rather
tearing the instructor apart, simply explain your situation and get with someone who understands and is
compatible with you.

I went through 3 trainers learning how to drive my
truck.  Now, 4 years later, I can laugh about it a little.

Watch plane crash stories on you tube.  You will notice that the pilots many times either not getting along or not talking at all.  They can't work together.  Can't have that.

Some instructors may be on the bottom rung of the piloting ladder anyways, struggling themselves.

I would play the field and look around a little.
Interview people and visit other airfields.

Might be the best move, particularly considering what
lessons cost. Good luck.

Bob